# Expresso Store Downloads

Tags: expresso-store, file-uploads

I must be missing something obvious.

I am trying to add a downloadable product in Expresso Store.

I have a channel with a custom file filed {products_download} as well as the Store Product Details field

I create the entry, upload the file, then after I purchase the product there is no link to download on my order page.

```
<h2>Order Summary / Tax Invoice</h2>
{exp:store:orders member_id="CURRENT_USER"}
<h1>Thank you for your Order:</h1>

<h2>Ordered Items:</h2>
    <ul>
    {items}
    <li>
        <h3>{title} -- {price}</h3>
        {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
            {exp:store:download url="{products_download}"}
                Download
            {/exp:store:download}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </li>
    {/items}
    </ul>
{/exp:store:orders}
```

The above outputs the title and price fine, just not the link to download

EE ver 2.4
Store ver 1.6.2

Comment: I think you are missing the order_id="{order_id}" parameter in the {exp:store:download} tag

Comment: actually when I add order_id="{order_id}" I get nothing displayed.  The title -- price are not even displayed

Comment: {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
            {exp:store:download url="{products_download}" order_id="{order_id}"}
                Download
            {/exp:store:download}
        {/exp:channel:entries}

Answer (score 1):

This was it:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    {exp:store:download url="{products_download}" order_id="{order_id}"}
        Download
    {/exp:store:download}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

thanks John